# WPF IValueConverter.ConvertBack not called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I have some code below which is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.  I'm using a converter to try to fill a DataGrid with data from a model that I have.  The DataGrid is being populated correctly, but any changes in the grid are not being persisted back to the objects.  I have specified the mode as TwoWay.  When I put a breakpoint on the converters ConvertBack method, it is never being called.

I am fairly new to WPF and MVVM, so I don't see what I'm doing wrong.  There is not much I can do to change the model, so I'd like to see if this can work unless there is a clearly superior method.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleBindingProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleBindingProblem"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ScenarioDataTableConverter x:Key="ScenarioDataTableConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Scenarios}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ScenarioDataTableConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace SampleBindingProblem
{
    public class ColumnInfo
    {
        public static readonly String[] ColumnLabels = new String[] { "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable5" };
    }

    public class ScenarioOption
    {
        public String Label { get; set; }
        public String[] Variables { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scenario
    {
        public ScenarioOption[] Options { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ScenarioDataTableConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public Object Convert (Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return (null);

            ScenarioOption[] options = (ScenarioOption[]) value;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("Label", typeof(String));
            for (Int32 c = 0; c < ColumnInfo.ColumnLabels.Length; ++c)
                table.Columns.Add(ColumnInfo.ColumnLabels[c], typeof(String));
            foreach (ScenarioOption option in options)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                List<String> lst = new List<String>();
                lst.Add(option.Label);
                lst.AddRange(option.Variables);
                row.ItemArray = lst.ToArray();
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return (table.DefaultView);
        }

        public Object ConvertBack (Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (null);
        }
    }

    internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void RaisePropertyChanged (String property)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = null;

        public ObservableCollection<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }

        public ViewModel ()
        {
            Scenario s1 = new Scenario();
            s1.Options = new ScenarioOption[] {
                new ScenarioOption() { Label = "Opt1", Variables=new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" } },
                new ScenarioOption() { Label = "Opt2", Variables=new String[] { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" } },
                new ScenarioOption() { Label = "Opt3", Variables=new String[] { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" } },
            };
            Scenario s2 = new Scenario();
            s2.Options = new ScenarioOption[] {
                new ScenarioOption() { Label = "Opt1", Variables=new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" } },
                new ScenarioOption() { Label = "Opt2", Variables=new String[] { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" } },
                new ScenarioOption() { Label = "Opt3", Variables=new String[] { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" } },
            };

            this.Scenarios = new ObservableCollection<Scenario>();
            this.Scenarios.Add(s1);
            this.Scenarios.Add(s2);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void Application_Startup (Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            window.DataContext = new ViewModel();
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ConvertBack() method currently returns null because I haven't implemented it since it so far has not been called.

Answer (score 2):

Converters don't work that way when it comes to collections. `ConvertBack` will only be called when the *entire* collection is replaced. It won't be called when an item in the collection is modified. In your case the collection (the DataView) isn't being replaced with a new DataView instance, but rather modified, and that's why `ConvertBack` isn't being called.

If you ask me, I don't see why you need to use the converter anyway. Either bind directly to the `Scenarios` property and work on this collection that is exposed by the view model, or alternatively call the conversion code in your viewmodel and expose the resulting `DataView` in a different property. Then you'll just need to bind to that property without specifying a converter.

Comment: The ListBox is already bound to Scenarios as the view is to allow multiple scenarios to be worked on.  It is the option collection within the scenario that I'm trying to get to the grid.  So what you're saying is to implement a property in Scenario which gets/sets a DataView?

Comment: That would probably be the easiest way to go. Just make sure you remove the converter.

Comment: I've been playing with that and so far the behavior seems exactly the same.  The setter on the DataView never gets called.

Comment: And it's not supposed to. Just look in the values that it holds and see if they're the new ones.

Comment: How are the model or the view model supposed to do that?

Comment: Again, it's the values that inside the DataView which are being set, not the DataView itself.

Comment: This is MVVM.  I don't have a variable pointing to the view just lying around in the VM or the model.  How and when am I supposed to be able to get the values out?

Comment: @WalterWilliams Because of the binding, the values are always kept updated in the viewmodel. If you want to display them in the view, use binding. If you need them in you viewmodel, the VM's properties are available to you.

Comment: @WalterWilliams I believe most of your questions stem from misunderstanding of MVVM basics. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is a great resource to refresh your knowledge.

Comment: I am learning, but what I think you don't understand is that the DataTable/DataView is not the model here; the DataTable/DataView is only the container to get it to display correctly in the view.  The getter for the DataView in the VM gets creates the DataView from the model anew every time.  I can't go and completely change the model implementation just to suit this one case.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like the classic beginner's mistake... I think that you need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your model classes. The idea is that you inform the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface when any property value changes. From the linked page on MSDN:

```
public string CustomerName
{
    get
    {
        return this.customerNameValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.customerNameValue)
        {
            this.customerNameValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The UI can then be updated from the model class and the model class will be able to be updated from changes in the UI. See the linked page on MSDN for the full example.

---

Also, you don't need to declare a `ResourceDictionary` in the `Window.Resources` section... it *is* a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ScenarioDataTableConverter x:Key="ScenarioDataTableConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is for updating the UI. His problem is with the other way around - updating the objects from the UI.

Comment: The ResourceDictionary is a relic of the simplification; there are other things in the real code.  The model also are POCOs from a different assembly.  I'd hope not to have to add that to the other assembly, but it could be possible to inherit the class and implement the interface.